The Most General Form of the Well-Ordering Theorem
What is the most general form of the well-ordering theorem? I ask because I wanted to share the following:

In its most general form the Well-Ordering Theorem is the following: Any collection of things can be well ordered. Where the words “collection” and “things” are primitive notions. And for any collection of things, it is “well-ordered” if and only if it has a first member.
Thus, the Well-Ordering Theorem in Mathematics is a universal instantiation of 1.
Thus, Aquinas’s Argument from Motion is a universal instantiation of  1
Thus, my generalization of Aquinas’s Argument from Motion is a universal instantiation of 1 too.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
